# Darf "mahlen" ein regelmäßiges Verb genannt werden?

Tags: grammar-identification, conjugation, past-participle, irregular-verb

Da das Verb "mahlen" keine Vokaländerung durchmacht, warum ist es nicht regelmäßig? Und wenn es doch regelmäßig ist, warum ist sein Partizip dann "gemahlen" und nicht einfach "gemahlt"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Früher (bis ins 17. Jahrhundert hinein) wurde das Verb *mahlen* stark (unregelmäßig) konjugiert (ähnlich wie *fahren* oder *tragen*):

> Ich mahle Weizen zu Mehl.
> Du mählst Weizen zu Mehl.
> Der Müller mählt Weizen zu Mehl.
> Gestern muhl ich Weizen zu Mehl.
>
> Weizen wird zu Mehl gemahlen.

Das hat sich dann geändert, und heute ist *mahlen* ein schwaches (regelmäßiges) Verb (vergleichbar mit *zahlen* oder *prahlen*):

> Ich mahle Weizen zu Mehl.
> Du mahlst Weizen zu Mehl.
> Der Müller mahlt Weizen zu Mehl.
> Gestern mahlte ich Weizen zu Mehl.

Einzig und allein das Partizip II besteht auch heute noch in seiner ursprünglichen Form weiter:

> Weizen wird zu Mehl <del>*gemahlt*</del> gemahlen.

---

In den alten Formen (z.B. *»Gestern muhl der Müller Mehl«*) erkennt man auch noch die enge Verwandtschaft der Wörter *mahlen, Mehl, Müller, Müll, Mühle* sowie *malmen, Malz, Malter, mild* und *Milbe.*

Comment: Echt jetzt, auch MIlbe?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: Ja. *»Milbe«* (althochdeutsch, ca. 9. Jhd *milwa*, auch *miliwa*) war ursprünglich die Bezeichnung für die Kleidermotte = kleines Tier, das Staub macht. *Mehl* (althochdeutsch *melo*, mittelhochdeutsch *mel*) hatte damals nämlich neben der heute noch geltenden Bedeutung *gemahlenes Getreide* auch die Bedeutungen *Staub, Erde, Kehricht, gelöschter Kalk.*. Als *miliwe* (das ist mittelhochdeutsch) wurde später jedes winzige Insekt bezeichnet, und so wurde der Name auf die winzigen Spinnentiere übertragen.